# Return multiple objects from a method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, methods, return-value

I have a method that takes an NSMutableArray as a parameter, and I would like it to return that array, another array that is created in the method, and an int created by the method.  I realize this could be done by making an array that had all these objects in it, and returning that, then removing them from the array outside the method, but is there another way to return multiple objects?

Comment: So basically the easiest way to do this is going to just be putting the values in a dictionary or array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using an `NSDictionary` to return multiple values is the customary way to do this in Obj-C.

The method signature would look something like this:

```
-(NSDictionary *)doSomeStuffThatReturnsMultipleObjects;
```

and you are going to want to define your dictionary keys in the appropriate files.

```
// Header File
extern NSString *const JKSourceArray;
extern NSString *const JKResultsArray;
extern NSString *const JKSomeNumber;

// Implementation File
NSString *const JKSourceArray = @"JKSourceArray";
NSString *const JKResultsArray = @"JKResultsArray";
NSString *const JKSomeNumber = @"JKSomeNumber";
```

The advantage over using an array is that the the order of elements and the presence/absence of elements doesn't matter, making it far easier to extend in the future, if you want to return additional objects. It's also far more flexible and extensible than passing by reference.

Answer (score 9):

The typical ways to pass back multiple values are to:

- Add extra parameters by reference (ex. typically NSErrors are passed
  this way)
- Pass them back in some other struct or object, typically an
  NSDictionary or a custom class

The above are good solutions for many situations, but here is another solution that may work best in other situations:

Add a block to your method:

```
- (void)myMethodWithMultipleReturnObjectsForObject:(id)object returnBlock:(void (^)(id returnObject1, id returnObject2))returnBlock
{
    // do stuff

    returnBlock(returnObject1, returnObject2);
}
```

Then use the method like this:

```
[myMethodWithMultipleReturnObjectsForObject:object returnBlock:^(id returnObject1, id returnObject2) {
    // Use the return objects inside the block
}];
```

The return objects in the above example are only usable within the block, so if you want to keep them around for use outside the block, just set some __block vars.

```
// Keep the objects around for use outside of the block
__block id object1;
__block id object2;
[myMethodWithMultipleReturnObjectsForObject:object returnBlock:^(id returnObject1, id returnObject2) {
    object1 = returnObject1;
    object2 = returnObject2;
}];
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more abut that? How could I declare the block in this case?

Comment: @Tulon I'm not sure what you mean. I already show the block's declaration in the first chunk of code in my example.

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can do it is have the user pass a pointer which they want to use to hold the data. Here is a sample that returns an array and uses pointers to give you an int value and another array. EDIT ok here is the working version I just tested it myself:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)doStuff:(int*)container returnedArray:(NSMutableArray*)arrayContainer{
   int a = 4;
   *container = a;
   [arrayContainer removeAllObjects];
   [arrayContainer addObject:@"object"];
   return [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"object",nil];
}
```

That way you could say like:

```
int value = 0;
NSMutableArray* new = [NSMutableArray array];
[self doStuff:&value returnedArray:new];
```

And it basicly works like a return!

Comment: Although the general technique you describe is one that's used in real programs, that code is totally broken and will not do what is intended at all. You seem to have some misconceptions about how pointers work, and also about variable scope.

Comment: Yeah, I thought this seemed a little off. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @Chuck I didn't test it I was just giving a sample of the concept and I wrote that in very little time. I was just trying to get him in the right direction.

Comment: @Chuck some of my wording might be a little off but the basics should work.

Comment: @Regan like chuck said it really does work you might just want to find a better example...

Comment: It isn't that your "wording is a little off." It's that your code is completely wrong. The only thing it does correctly is return an NSMutableArray containing the string `@"object"`. The type of the `arrayContainer` variable is wrong and the `container` pointer is never dereferenced, so it can't affect anything outside of your function.

Comment: @Chuck ok I will give an actual example I use.

Comment: @Chuck @Regan Ok I fixed it and checked it myself. Even chuck will agree with me this time.

Comment: That'll "work", but if I ever found code like that in something I was working on, I'd immediately rewrite it. ;)

Comment: @bbum Far enough I wouldm't do the array thing either but I do like the integer one.

Comment: As edited, works beautifully!  Perfect for a method that returns 3 CGRects.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider returning a struct.

```
typedef struct {
    NSMutableArray *array1;
    NSArray *array2;
    NSInteger integer;
} MyAwesomeReturnValue;
```

Your method could now look like this:

```
- (MyAwesomeReturnValue)myAwesomeMethod:(NSMutableArray *)parameter
{
    MyAwesomeReturnValue retval;
    retval.array1 = parameter;
    retval.array2 = [NSArray array];
    retval.integer = 5;

    return retval;
}
```

And you'd use it like:

```
- (void)anotherAwesomeMethod
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    MyAwesomeReturnValue returnedValue = [self myAwesomeMethod:array];

    NSLog(@"%@", returnedValue.array1);
    NSLog(@"%@", returnedValue.array2);
    NSLog(@"%d", returnedValue.integer);
}
```

Hope that helped. ;)

Comment: I don't like the `myAwesomeMethod` example.  You are creating a local parameter named retval, and returning that as the result.  But as soon as you pop the stack, you lose that local parameter.  It would be different if that was an object, but this is just a standard C struct.

Comment: @Christian Schnorr, How could you set `NSMutableArray` in `struct`. There should be an error.

Comment: @Tulon How? NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray?

Comment: @Rickster Just came back to this. Wouldn't the structure be copied once returned from the method though, hence actually being safe?

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr, `ARC` enable code and you will get
Error: `ARC forbids Objective - C objects in struct` at line `NSMutableArray *array1;` in `typedef struct`...

Comment: @Tulon Yeah I guess you're right. This code is pretty old. You should use kubi's approach from above.